# Express wildcard route overwriting other routes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, routes

I'm currently making a `Node.js` server using `Express.js` and `Typescript`. I have a `routes` folder in which I create `.ts` files containing routes. One of these files may look something like this:

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";

export const router: Router = Router();

router.get("/", (_: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.json({
        message: "Hello world",
    });
});

export const path = "/users";
```

In my main file `server.ts` I dynamically add all routes using the exported variables in the routes. This looks something like this:

```
// set __dirname
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const routesPath: string = path.join(__dirname, "routes");

// register routes
try {
    fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(async (file: string) => {
        const route: { path: string; router: Router } = await import(
            `./routes/${file}`
        );

        app.use(route.path, route.router);
    });

    // ! Causes Issue
    app.all("*", (_: Request, res: Response) =>
        res.status(404).json({
            message: "Not found",
            status: 404,
        })
    );
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

In the route below that has the `*` route I'm getting an issue where when it is uncommented it overwrites all other routes to itself but the routes work normally when I have it commented out. What may be causing this? I also tried to move the `404` route before registering all routes but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of the loop block running asynchronously, even though you have defined `app.all("*", ...)` after the `forEach`, but it will be executed before `forEach`.

So you need to change the `forEach` part like below:

```js
await Promise.all(fs.readdirSync(routesPath).map(async (file: string) => {
    const route: { path: string; router: Router } = await import(
        `./routes/${file}`
    );

    app.use(route.path, route.router);
}));

app.all("*", (_: Request, res: Response) =>
    res.status(404).json({
        message: "Not found",
        status: 404,
    })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async function registerRoutes() {
let files = fs.readdirSync(routesPath);
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  let file = files[i];
  const route = await import(`./routes/${file}`);

  app.use(route.path, route.router);
  console.log("register ");
}
console.log("final");
app.use("*", (_, res) =>
  res.status(404).json({
    message: "Not found",
    status: 404,
  })
);
```

}

Comment: That wouldn't work. `.use` is applied to **all** requests whereas I need `.all` to be applied to all requests that **don't already exist**.

Comment: yes .use is applied is to all requests but if you put it at the bottom of your route middlewares it means at that point it's handling "all requests  that don't already exist" or that don't match any of your routes

Comment: How would that look? Could you add a bit of code to show what you mean since I might've misunderstood you.

Comment: i have run your code and the problem is the forEach loop which is an async loop so your routes are registered after app.all("*") so to solve your problem i try to use for loop which is synchronous try the above function don't forget to call it after defining it